# MySql trava ao tentar consultar tabela com muitos registros (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-select, crud

Estou tentando fazer um filtro em que a consulta é feita em uma tabela em que o id do último registro está no numero **468.466**.

No filtro, preciso fazer a comparação com uma View, que tem seu id do último registro **5.303.345**.

A query é a seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_name1
left join tb_name2 using (id)
```

Ao tentar fazê-la, fica muito tempo carregando e não termina, pois até trava o meu computador todo, preciso reiniciá-lo no botão.

Alguma solução para eu conseguir executar esse filtro?

Comment: Que tal paginar? Por que precisa de tantos registros de uma vez só?

Comment: os ids não significam muito, você pode ter apagado a tabela 1 e ter começado do 468465, certo? mas você tem certeza que quer retornar tudo isso de registros? não pode testar primeiro usando um `limit` ou alguma condição no `where`? supondo que a view tenha mesmo 5+milhões de registros, esse join vai demorar mesmo, mas não deve ser o suficiente para travar. Aliás, ao usar `using` para o join, tem certeza que as duas tabelas usam `id` como chave (primária e estrangeira)?

Comment: Certo, posso por o limite.
Mas preciso listar os dados... O que faço com o restante que não foi listado?
Sim, dei um count e a tabela tem quase 200mil registro. O que já é muito.
Tudo bem que tem um campo para pesquisa. Poderia listar alguns e deixar o resto para pesquisa.

Comment: Mas você precisa de todos os registros ao mesmo tempo? Por que? Para paginar, basta você trabalhar com limite e offset, mostrando cada página de registros por vez, conforme for demandado.

Comment: Sim. Se eu mostrar cada pagina por vez, eu preciso criar uma instrução no meu código para mostrar na próxima pagina, sempre 1 registro a partir do ultimo da pagina anterior, certo?